# AWS-EC2-Windows Servers Fail to Start Programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have created a nifty calendar web application that controls the state of the instances in in my AWS environment. My test environment consisted of a few Amazon Linux instances, and all was working as intended. After setting this web application up in an environment with both Windows and Linux servers, I have noticed that the Windows servers stop properly, but when they're started programmatically they go into a "pending" state, then back to stopped.

Would anyone be able to give me some insight on why the Windows servers would behave differently? If not, point me in the right direction to generating the appropriate logs to troubleshoot the issue?

I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the CloudTrail service in AWS and replicating the error. CloudTrail will keep track of all of the API calls for starting and stopping instances, and you can see if there's anything unexpected (i.e. a "StopInstances" right after a "StartInstances", which I'm guessing this is). If there is no stray API call and you are sure you are only sending a "StartInstances" command, this question is best suited for AWS support.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue didnt have to do with windows, it was that we had encrypted the volumes of only our windows machines and needed to grant the appropriate permissions to the Lambda function to access KMS. Sadly I believe this problem occurs silently, no trace of the issue in cloudwatch. Luckily, the issue is resolved. I appreciate the input, quercy, I was a bit light on explaining what i had already checked.